# an obect (jw player) disappears if I store it in $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I need to access my JW Player object on different pages of the website to load up playlists.

So I added one line of code and the player vanishes!

```
<?php $_SESSION['theJwPlayer'] = jwplayer; ?>
```

I use the following at the top of any page wherever I need to access the $_SESSION:

```
session_start();
```

Here's the creation of the player, this works fine, for over a week, except the last line of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
       'flashplayer': 'http://localhost/theWebsite/jwplayer/player.swf',
       'id': 'playerID',
       'width': '480',
       'height': '270',
       'file':  'http://localhost/theWebsite/videos/moto_sounds.flv',
       'image':   'http://localhost/theWebsite/images/banner2.jpg'
   });


 // now save the player in a session variable
 <?php $_SESSION['theJwPlayer'] = jwplayer; ?>

</script>
```

If I simply remove that one line of php code that stores the player in the _SESSION array, the web page with the player goes back to normal, they way it's been for over a week, *stable*, the JW player shows up, no problem.  But add this one line and the player vanishes:

I thought sessions automatically serialize objects?   Why is this one line of code 'disappearing' my jwplayer object?
I tried adding the $ before jwplayer, as in

```
<?php $_SESSION['theJwPlayer'] = $jwplayer; ?>
```

No change, the player vanishes.  What's happening here?

Comment: What you are trying to do is fundamentally impossible. What you *could* do is store the *code* that initializes the player in the $_SESSION array.

Comment: You're trying to store a dream in your pillowcase so you can re-dream it the next night. Problem is, the dream doesn't exist after you wake up so there's nothing to store.

Comment: @hakre - just fyi, it's annoying to be told that.  Here's why.  Just last night, about 2 weeks after starting to code with PHP etc. I finally understood enough to go back and 'accept' some answers from last week.  Look at my newness here in terms of rep and time of signup.  I would say 'lay off the newbs' - it comes off as 'here let me whap you over the head with something you already know.'  I've been told 'accept' too many times Be considerate and give us TIME to even recognize what should be accepted!  And we don't want to guess, 'accept' something you don't even understand is a lie!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to store a JavaScript object instance into a PHP variable. That is impossible. The best you could do if you must have the object would be to store the whole bit of Javascript, including the `<script>` tags, escaping properly, and echoing it out. But you should just include it as another file if you're using lots of places, rather than keeping it in PHP's memory.

Comment: Aha. How then can I get access to my jwplayer on other web pages to adjust its playlists, there must be a way?

Comment: @wantTheBest: use a php include as josh suggested... or create the playist as a php array, json_encode it end echo it in your script tag.

Comment: thanks, sounds like you're saying to do an 'include_once'  the file with the jwplayer.setup() call, that way -- any other file that does the include_once will have access to the jwplayer variable?